# Solve $- \Delta_pu = |u|^{q - 2}u$ via the Ekeland Variational Principle - Is my solution correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, calculus-of-variations

I am studying the Ekeland Variational Principle, and doing some exercises on the subject, but I lack confidence. I would be very thankful if someone could read my solution and verify its correctness or point out any mistakes.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

**Problem**
Use the Ekeland Variational Principle to solve the  following sublinear problem:
$$
(P)\quad
\begin{cases}
- \Delta_pu = |u|^{q - 2}u \quad \text{ in } \Omega, \\
u = 0 \quad \text{ on } \partial \Omega
\end{cases} 
$$
where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain of $\Bbb{R}^N$, $N \geq 3$, $2 \leq p \leq N$ and $p - 1 \leq q \leq p$. $\Delta_p$ denotes the $p$-laplacian operator.

**Solution**

A weak solution to problem $(P)$ is a critical point of the functional
$$
I(u) = \frac1p \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^p \ dx - \frac1q \int_\Omega |u|^q \ dx = \frac1p ||u||^p - \frac1q ||u||_q^q, \quad u \in W_0^{1, p} (\Omega),
$$
which is of class $C^1$ with
$$
I'(u)v = \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^{p - 2} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \ dx - \int_\Omega |u|^{q - 2}uv \ dx, \quad v \in W_0^{1, p} (\Omega). 
$$

We know that $I$ is weakly lower semicontinuous and coercive. Then it is bounded from below. Let $c = \inf_{W_0^{1, p} (\Omega)}I$. By the Ekeland Variational Principle, there exists a Palais-Smale sequence at the level $c$. If we show that $I$ satisfies $(PS)_c$, we are done.

Let $(u_n) \subset W_0^{1, p} (\Omega)$ be a Palais-Smale sequence at the level $c$, that is, 
$$
I(u_n) \to c, \quad I'(u_n) \to 0.
$$ 
We claim that $(u_n)$ has a convergent subsequence. First, note that $(u_n)$ is bounded. Since $W_0^{1, p} (\Omega)$ is reflexive, there is some $u \in W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ such that $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $W_0^{1, p} (\Omega)$. Then, by the compact Sobolev embeddings, we have that 
$$
u_n \to u \quad \text{ in } L^s(\Omega), 
$$
for $s \in [1, p^*)$. In particular, this convergence holds for $s = q$.

Now, we want to show that 
$$
||u_n - u||^p = \int_\Omega |\nabla(u_n - u)|^p \ dx \to 0.
$$
But note that 
$$
\frac1p ||u_n - u||^p = I'(u_n - u)(u_n - u) + \frac1q ||u_n - u||_q^q \to 0, 
$$
since $I'(u_n) \to 0$ since $(u_n)$ is a Palais-Smale sequence, $I'(u)(u_n - u) \to 0$ by the weak convergence and $u_n - u \to 0$ in $L^q(\Omega)$ by the compact Sobolev embedding. Hence $u_n \to u$ in $W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ and the claim is proved.

The limit $u$ is a critical point of $I$, hence a weak solution to problem $(P)$. It only remains to show that $u$ is not the trivial solution. Let $\psi \in C_c^\infty (\Omega)$ such that $\psi > 0$. Then for $t > 0$ we have that 
$$
I(t \psi) = \frac{t^p}{p} ||\psi||^p - \frac{t^q}{q} ||\psi||_q^q < 0
$$
if $t$ is sufficiently small. Hence $I(u) < 0 = I(0)$, so $u$ is not the trivial solution.

Comment: What is "Corolário 6.3"?

Comment: Sorry, I just copied my written solution and forgot to change this. It says that a $C^1$ functional that satisfies $(PS)_c$ where $c$ is the infimum attains the infimum and therefore has a critical point

Comment: That's not a problem, if you specify the text you are reading. Also, what do you mean by $(PS)_c$? I guess this means that every sequence $u_n\in W^{1,p}_0$ such that $I(u_n)=c$ and $I'(u_n)\to 0$ has a convergent subsequence, isn't it?

Comment: Correct, it satisfies the Palais-Smale condition at level c. About specifying the text, it is some lecture notes in portuguese of a professor of my University, so I think it wouldn't help much. I have edited the question

Comment: Ok, you actually say this in the text. I read the solution and it seems OK to me

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your help